# Converter Json em XML

Tags: c#, json, xml

Tenho esse código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Xml;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace PowderToyUpdater
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            WebClient web = new WebClient();
            var value = web.DownloadString("http://powdertoy.co.uk/Browse/Comments.json?ID=1681176&Start=0&Count=20");


            XmlDocument xdoc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(value);

            XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create("comments_.xml");
            xdoc.WriteTo(w);
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace PowderToyUpdater
{
    public struct Comment
    {
        public string Username;
        public string Userid;
        //public string Gravatar;
        public string CommentContent;
        public string Timestamp;
        public string FormattedUsername;
    }
}
```

Mas quando o JSON é convertido para XML e armazenado em um arquivo, parte do XML fica faltando.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><User><root><Username>Sandwichlizard</Username><UserID>105412</UserID><Gravatar>/Avatars/105412_40.png</Gravatar><Text>front page.</Text><Timestamp>1424281388</Timestamp><FormattedUsername>Sandwichlizard</FormattedUsername></root><root><Username>ndutoit</Username><UserID>133746</UserID><Gravatar>http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/88ff6ca3f7391896d88ea1f6ac46c3f8?s=40&amp;amp;d=http%3A%2F%2Fpowdertoy.co.uk%2FDesign%2FImages%2FAvatar.png&amp;amp;r=pg</Gravatar><Text>what is fp?</Text><Timestamp>1424279967</Timestamp><FormattedUsername>ndutoit</FormattedUsername></root><root><Username>Lord_Bowserinator</Username><UserID>130740</UserID><Gravatar>/Avatars/130740_40.png</Gravatar><Text>fp again</Text><Timestamp>1417569227</Timestamp><FormattedUsername>Lord_Bowserinator</FormattedUsername></root><root><Username>Sandwichlizard</Username><UserID>105412</UserID><Gravatar>/Avatars/105412_40.png</Gravatar><Text>sure.  I will make a tutorial save.  that will be easier than just talking about it here.  I will leave a link in this save when it is ready.  I will also publish it.</Text><Timestamp>1417561239</Timestamp><FormattedUsername>Sandwichlizard</FormattedUsername></root><root><Username>Anonymous100</Username><UserID>92366</UserID><Gravatar>/Avatars/92366_40.png</Gravatar><Text>Sandwich would you mind explaining to me the basic of all thesse fancy filt drives? I know that it has something to do with the fact that a color of filt when beamed at dtec with aray changes the filts color that is next to the dtec, but I dont understand how that info is decoded, and how it is written in the first place.</Text><Timestamp>1417541787</Timestamp><FormattedUsername>Anonymous100</FormattedUsername></root><root><Username>tombattraw</Username><UserID>85950</UserID><Gravatar>http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a9a4ec31425b097ae496b8f027cdf016?s=40&amp;amp;d=http%3A%2F%2Fpowdertoy.co.uk%2FDesign%2FImages%2FAvatar.png&amp;amp;r=pg</Gravatar><Text>try recording a pong game</Text><Timestamp>1417535992</Timestamp><FormattedUsername>tombattraw</FormattedUsername></root><root><Username>Sandwichlizard</Username><UserID>105412</UserID><Gravatar>/Avatars/105412_40.png</Gravatar><Text>@mecha-man.  sure. I have already started.  I am working on a new printer save using this drive and I realized I needed some things and it forced me into a redesign.  I will PM you.</Text><Timestamp>1417488946</Timestamp><FormattedUsername>Sandwichlizard</FormattedUsername></root><root><Username>mecha-man</Username><UserID>48475</UserID><Gravatar>/Avatars/48475_40.png</Gravatar><Text>@Sandwichlizard: Wanna work together to make it more compact?</Text><Timestamp>1417482098</Timestamp><FormattedUsername>mecha-man</FormattedUsername></root><root><Username>159819</Username><UserID>78051</UserID><Gravatar>/Avatars/78051_40.png</Gravatar><Text>is it posable to ither make a biger screen or smaler pixels?</Text><Timestamp>1417478468</Timestamp><FormattedUsername>159819</FormattedUsername></root><root><Username>0356459</Username><UserID>121388</UserID><Gravatar>http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/56261703f558a3503a1ab238fd4f4dac?s=40&amp;amp;d=http%3A%2F%2Fpowdertoy.co.uk%2FDesign%2FImages%2FAvatar.png&amp;amp;r=pg</Gravatar><Text>sorry man......but hey front page for a long time! :)</Text><Timestamp>1417412356</Timestamp><FormattedUsername>0356459</FormattedUsername></root><root><Username>Sandwichlizard</Username><UserID>105412</UserID><Gravatar>/Avatars/105412_40.png</Gravatar><Text>If someone would like to make a new video for this setup I would happily update the save with credit to the author of said video</Text><Timestamp>1417399984</Timestamp><FormattedUsername>Sandwichlizard</FormattedUsername></root><root><Username>Sandwichlizard</Username><UserID>105412</UserID><Gravatar>/Avatars/105412_40.png</Gravatar><Text>the crappy video is just to demo the drive.  video made way better video's than mine for sure.  thank you for your input.</Text><Timestamp>1417399892</Timestamp><FormattedUsername>Sandwichlizard</FormattedUsername></root><root><Username>0356459</Username><UserID>121388</UserID><Gravatar>http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/56261703f558a3503a1ab238fd4f4dac?s=40&amp;amp;d=http%3A%2F%2Fpowdertoy.co.uk%2FDesign%2FImages%2FAvatar.png&amp;amp;r=pg</Gravatar><Text>video did it better 2 times before. -1</Text><Timestamp>1417318433</Timestamp><FormattedUsername>0356459</FormattedUsername></root><root><Username>zsdrfty</Username><UserID>100327</UserID><Gravatar>/Avatars/100327_40.png</Gravatar><Text>Minecraft is more insane because it has analog computers. oog</Text><Timestamp>1417281395</Timestamp><FormattedUsername>zsdrfty</FormattedUsername></root><root><Username>Imperator</Username><UserID>123921</UserID><Gravatar>/Avatars/123921_40.png</Gravatar><Text>It's so cool that people can actually make a functioning computer within a game.</Text><Timestamp>1417269917</Timestamp><FormattedUsername>Imperator</FormattedUsername></root><root><Username>handicraftsman</Username><UserID>108835</UserID><Gravatar>/Avatars/108835_40.png</Gravatar><Text>Sandwichlizard, you can use my tablets without credits ) It's for you ) id:1677416</Text><Timestamp>1417268811</Timestamp><FormattedUsername>handicraftsman</FormattedUsername></root><root><Username>Ilog123</Username><UserID>104909</UserID><Gravatar>/Avatars/104909_40.png</Gravatar><Text>Try Making a Movie maker so you can copy/paste your film and check em out</Text><Timestamp>1417251254</Timestamp><FormattedUsername>Ilog123</FormattedUsername></root><root><Username>electronic_steve</Username><UserID>96362</UserID><Gravatar>/Avatars/96362_40.png</Gravatar><Text>id:1683229 108,3... i won!</Text><Timestamp>1417237206</Timestamp><FormattedUsername>electronic_steve</FormattedUsername></root><root><Username>zsdrfty</Username><UserID>100327</UserID><Gravatar>/Avatars/100327_40.png</Gravatar><Text>16.7k? We're over 1/10 of the capacity of a single-sided, single-density 5.25" floppy disk!</Text><Timestamp>1417229000</Timestamp><FormattedUsername>zsdrfty</FormattedUsername></root><root><Username>Fulchrum</Username><UserID>95857</UserID><Gravata  <= Aqui falta o restante do xml.
```

E depois de converter o JSON para XML, como faço para utilizar XmlTextReader ou XmlReader?

Comment: No titulo da pergunta é para converter json para objeto, no corpo da pergunta você está falando sobre um XML cortado. Compõe a pergunta corretamente.

Comment: Por que você precisa dos dados como XML? Não seria melhor armazena-los como JSON já que ele está sendo obtidos do web service dessa forma?

Comment: Nathan, por qual motivo minha resposta não resolveu seu problema? Eu testei o que eu disse nela muito bem antes de postar aqui, e mesmo assim estou com -1. Isso não me parece nada justo.

Answer (score 1):

É recomendado que você utilize o método [`XmlDocument.Save`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.save(v=vs.110).aspx) para gravar esse documento XML em um arquivo. A utilização dele é bem simples, veja como alterei o trecho do método Main do seu código para utiliza-lo:

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
var value = $"{{ user: {web.DownloadString("http://powdertoy.co.uk/Browse/Comments.json?ID=1681176&Start=0&Count=20")} }}";

XmlDocument xdoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(value, "root");

xdoc.Save("comments_.xml");
```

Note também que fiz uma alteração no JSON obtido do web service para que ele se tornasse válido para conversão pelo método `JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode`. De acordo com a documentação do Json.NET para que você converter um documento JSON para XML, é necessário que esse documento JSON possua um único objeto na sua raiz. O JSON retornado pelo web service não seguia esse padrão e vinha no formato de array. [Essa página da documentação fala sobre isso.](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm)

Sobre a segunda parte da sua pergunta onde você pergunta sobre a utilização do [`System.Xml.XmlReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader(v=vs.110).aspx) ou [`System.Xml.XmlReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx).

Conforme descrito na documentação do `System.Xml.XmlReader`, sua utilização não é mais recomendada e o ´System.Xml.XmlReader` deve ser utilizado no seu lugar.

Como não valeria a pena que eu demonstrasse tudo que é possível fazer com o `System.Xml.XmlReader`, e sua pergunta também não explicitou exatamente o que você gostaria de fazer com ele, vou te recomendar ler a documentação dessa classe na MSDN, já você poderá encontrar vários exemplos de utilização bem explicados. [Documentação do `System.Xml.XmlReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Esse código abaixo vai gerar um XML sem cortes, fiz um [fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IYB73Q) para você com o código:

```js
WebClient web = new WebClient();
var value = web.DownloadString("http://powdertoy.co.uk/Browse/Comments.json?ID=1681176&Start=0&Count=20");

            string json = @"{
   '?xml': {
     '@version': '1.0',
     '@standalone': 'no'
   },
   'root': {
     'minhaclasse':
[
" + value.Replace("'","\'") + @"

]
  }
}";

XmlDocument xml = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);

xml.Save(@"c:\caminho\teste.xml");
```

Fiz um exemplo básico com XmlReader para você, o código abaixo também roda aqui no [fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tTzGHy).

```js
public class Program
{
 public static void Main()
 {
  
  String xmlString =
   @"<bookstore>
    <book genre='autobiography' publicationdate='1981-03-22' ISBN='1-861003-11-0'>
     <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
     <author>
      <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
      <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
     </author>
     <price>8.99</price>
    </book>
   </bookstore>";
  
  // Create an XmlReader
  using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))
  {
   reader.ReadToFollowing("book");
   reader.MoveToFirstAttribute();
   string genre = reader.Value;
   Console.WriteLine("The genre value: " + genre);
  
   reader.ReadToFollowing("title");
   Console.WriteLine("Content of the title element: " + reader.ReadElementContentAsString());
  }
 }
}
```

Ainda existe a opção de jogar o Json direto para objeto, digo isso pelo titulo da sua pergunta, que você alterou, caso interesse você pode pegar o link direto por webClient e transformar em um objeto qualquer criado por você. Nesse caso não teria que fazer nada com XML.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Conforme solicitado no comentário eu fiz um código juntando tudo.
Esse código não grava em arquivo, ele pega o Json, converte para XML, joga em uma String e faz a leitura. [Aqui (Fiddle)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/vlfHWs) você pode ver o código rodando.

```js
            WebClient web = new WebClient();
            var value = web.DownloadString("http://powdertoy.co.uk/Browse/Comments.json?ID=1681176&Start=0&Count=20");

            string json = @"{
   '?xml': {
     '@version': '1.0',
     '@standalone': 'no'
   },
   'root': {
     'minhaclasse':
[
" + value.Replace("'", "\'") + @"

]
  }
}";

            XmlDocument xml = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);


            var xmlString = xml.InnerXml;


            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))
            {
                reader.MoveToContent();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                    {

                        
                        if (reader.Name == "Username")
                        {
                            XElement el = XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
                            if (el != null)
                            {
                                Console.Write("Username : ");
                                Console.WriteLine(el.Value);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
}
```

Comment: Por favor poderia colocar do mesmo jeito mais com esse json aqui?
http://powdertoy.co.uk/Browse/Comments.json?ID=1681176&Start=0&Count=20

Comment: O exemplo de converter o json com para XML é com esse link aí.

Comment: Fiz um código que eu acho que é o que você quer. Se atender não esqueça de marcar a resposta.